# Browser's code processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having simple javascript code:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('#parent').append('<span>span</span>');
});
$('#btn2').click(function(){
    if ($('#parent span').length > 0)
        alert($('#parent span').text());
    else 
        alert('element doesn\'t exists yet!');
});
```

is it possible a user click btn2 so quick that appended span element does not exist yet?

Am i right that until the handler function for click event on btn1 ends and span is added to the document clicking on btn2 ends with no results just because the browser is processing btn1 handler?

Comment: We can't see your HTML, so we can't know for sure where you went wrong.  However, it's good practice to put your jQuery within a DOM ready event handler function.

Comment: No, inserting an element is synchronous and happens so fast that it's really not possible for the user to click the first button, and then move the mouse and click the second button so fast the element wasn't inserted yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In fact, clicking `#btn2` will not alert "span" unless you first clicked `#btn1`. If you wanted for the `<span>span</span>` to be loaded automatically, without requiring a button click, you could do like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#parent').append('<span>span</span>');

    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        if ($('#parent span').length > 0) {
            alert($('#parent span').text());
        } else {
            alert('element doesn\'t exists yet!');
        }
    });
});
```

Then your `<span>span</span>` will be appended automatically and clicking `#btn2` should always alert "span".